# find with -execdir: returning nonzero on test failure

Tags: bash, shell, find

I'm using the following command in my CI/CD system to run some unit tests that are in Go modules in subdirectories:

`find . -name go.mod -execdir go test -v -cover ./... \;`

...which works great, except that it always returns 0, even if a test fails, which makes it useless for CI.

Is there a some other way (other than a multi-line shell script) that I can have this command exit with error if `go test` fails?

(Note that each invocation of `go test` has to be executed in the subdirectory containing `go.mod`)

Comment: Instead of asking `find` to execute the tests, ask it to return the list of paths to `go.mod` files and read the list with a shell script that excutes them and handles their exit codes the way you want.

Comment: What exit code do you need? Do you want one reflecting all `go.mod` files (so if one fails, you get non-0 and 0 only if _all_ were successful) or do you need to capture each f them sparately?

Comment: A failure in a utility executed via `-exec` or `-execdir` is no failure in `find`, so `find` would not exit with a non-zero exit status. It would be better to use a loop over `./**/go.mod` (with `globstar` enabled).

Comment: @terdon You nailed it: if one execution of `go test` fails, the whole thing should return nonzero. But @Kusalananda points out that it's not really possible with `find` and `execdir`, so I might have to just use a loop instead. I was hoping for a one-liner, but I guess it's not a big deal to do a little shell scripting...